# Accessing elements within a JSONP object using JQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, object, jsonp

I am having issues accessing internal elements within my JSONP object. My JSONP looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "EntityID": "",
    "Address1": "",
    "Address2": "",
    "Address3": "",
    "Adult": bool,
    "Option": "",
    "NameFirst": "",
    "NameLast": "",
  },
  {
    "EntityID": "",
    "Address1": "",
    "Address2": "",
    "Address3": "",
    "Adult": bool,
    "Option": "",
    "NameFirst": "",
    "NameLast": "",
  }
]
```

How do I access the arrays? If I access it using something like this:

```
data = jsonp[i].EntityID;
```

All it returns is *undefined*

**Edit**

In Google Chromes console it displays this error:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'EntityID' of undefined*

I have also tried:

```
data = jsonp[1];
```

Which just returns an individual character whether it be a letter, number or even '{'.

I have tried a couple of other methods but they either return everything all at once, a single character or undefined. How can I access this correctly?

**Edit**

JQuery script that I am using. I thought it was pretty standard. I have used it on Twitters API before.

```
$(document).ready(function GetData() {
    var url = "http://";
    $.getJSON(url + '?callback=?', null, function(Data) {
        for(i in Data) {
            foo = Data[i];
            $('#Facilities').append('<div>' + foo[0].EntityID + '</div>');
            console.log(foo);
        } 
    })
})
```

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/CxV9c/15/

Comment: @AnoopJoshi That is exactly what I thought. But it still returns undefined.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi When I look at the error in Google Chrome's console it says that it is 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'EntityID' of undefined'

Comment: It sounds like you've got a string on your hands, not JSONP, if when you access a value in the array, you get an individual character, be it a letter, number or bracket. If you can use jQuery, you can use: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/ to turn your string into an JSON object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json is invalid. String values should be enclosed in double quotes. So you  cant give `bool` in the value. Either you can use `true` or `false`,

```
var jsonp=[
  {
    "EntityID": "",
    "Address1": "",
    "Address2": "",
    "Address3": "",
    "Adult": true,
    "Option": "",
    "NameFirst": "",
    "NameLast": "",
  },
  {
    "EntityID": "",
    "Address1": "",
    "Address2": "",
    "Address3": "",
    "Adult": true,
    "Option": "",
    "NameFirst": "",
    "NameLast": "",
  }
]
```

Then you can access the elements like,

```
alert(jsonp[0].EntityID);
```

If you want to use bool as value, 
use like this `"Adult": "bool",`

**Edit**

From the edited part of the quetion,
"Which just returns an individual character whether it be a letter, number or even '{'."

Then the response should be in string. Thats why you are getting each character while giving the index. So you need to parse the string to json object first.

USe `jQuery.parseJSON(` for that,

```
jsonp=jQuery.parseJSON(jsonp);
```

then you can access the elements in that object

```
$(document).ready(function GetData() {
    var url = "http://";
    $.getJSON(url + '?callback=?', null, function (Data) {
        Data = jQuery.parseJSON(Data);
        for (i in Data) {
            foo = Data[i];
            $('#Facilities').append('<div>' + foo[0].EntityID + '</div>');
            console.log(foo);
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: In the response it has 'true' 'false'. I put 'bool' to emphasize its type.

Comment: @Corey did you check that fiddle?

Comment: @Corey can you show us the code for getting jsonp.?